# Minimizing the ratio of two specific non negative quadratic convex functions

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

$F$ is $m\times m$ diagonal, with real non negative elements

$D$ is $n \times m$ complex

$P$ is $n \times 1$ complex

$A$ is $m \times 1$ complex.

Minimize $\Gamma(A)$, with respect to $A$.

$$\Gamma(A) = \frac{m^2(DA-P)^H (DA-P) + (FA)^H(FA)}{A^HA}$$

**It is known** that both numerator and denominator of $\Gamma(A)$ are **convex** and non negative. Also both the terms of the numerator are individually convex and non negative.

Question: An numerical optimization algorithm to find global minimum.

Apart from a reagular solution, I am also interested in a gradient descent based method if possible as  the matrices are large. Also $m >> n$.

PS : This question is a specific version of [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/31105/13214).

**EDIT** : more known information

No constraints on problem but

1. $\sum P = 0$, I mean sum of elements of matrix $P$ is zero.
2. Diagonal elements of $F$ are not all zeros.
3. Also $P^HP \ne 0$.
4. Rows of $D$ are orthogonal to each other. Also they are linearly independent.

Comment: Couple of questions: does $^H$ refer to the conjugate transpose? Also, what does $A(1, 1) = 0$ mean explicitly?

Comment: @TheoBendit : $^H$ means conjugate transpose. Please treat constraint $A(1,1) = 0$doesn't exist. $A(1,1) = 0$ doesnt mean anything to the optimization problem.its as good as this constraint is not there. You can see that if I make m = m-1, this  constraint would vanish. (it was a reference to my own problem)

Comment: @TheoBendit : edited to remove the constraint

Comment: Are there any constraints? I did not analyze it thoroughly, but there may be no minimum.

Comment: @AlexShtof : by no minimum you mean minimum is $-\infty$? No constraints on problem but $\sum P = 0$, I mean sum of elements of matrix $P$ is zero. Diagonal elements of $F$ are not all zeros. Also $P^HP \ne 0$. Columns of $D$ are orthogonal to each other.

Comment: I mean constraints on $A$. Even if the objective is bounded, without further constraints on $A$ it may not attain its infimum at any point.

Comment: @AlexShtof : I have edited to include known information. Let me know what you think is problem with $A$. What are you worried about?

Comment: @AlexShtof : One thing I know is $A(1,1) = 0$, but I don't think that would be a problem. Please let me know if this is useful to resolve.

Comment: Look at an very extreme case, when everything is one-dimensional and $\gamma(A) = \frac{|A|^2 + 1}{|A|^2}$. This function can get arbitrarily close to $1$, which is its lower bound, but at no point it will satisfy $\gamma(A) = 1$. I do not see why a similar case cannot happen under your problem assumptions.

Comment: @AlexShtof : You are looking at $A^HD^HP + P^HDA = 0$ for all $A$. In light of information about $P$ and $D$ that I have added at the bottom of the question, I am hoping that this condition won't arise. I have not verified, but hoping these conditions thwart this. Do you think its more about $P$ and $D$ than about $A$. If you can verify or have any clues how this condition won't arise, please do let me know.

Comment: Either you impose constrain $A$ to lie in some compact convex set, or you can prove that there exists $c$, which you can compute, such that the set defined by $\Gamma(A) \leq c$ is contained in some compact convex set  (meaning that you can add a constraint on $A$ without modifying the problem). Otherwise, I am neither aware of a result implying that the minimum exists, nor of an algorithm to solve your problem.

Comment: @AlexShtof : I don't think your condition arises. $A^HD^HP+P^HDA=0$ is not valid for all $A$, given the information about $P$ and $D$ at the bottom of the question. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @AlexShtof : It would still help if you could give a solution based on your suggested  assumptions. Thank you. I am interested in the algorithm.

Comment: There are many papers and algorithms. Here is one: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs10107-007-0181-x.pdf

Look for `quadratic fractional programming' in google scholar. You will find plenty :) 

The earliest general approach I am aware of is by DINKELBACH, in his well-known paper ' ON NONLINEAR FRACTIONAL PROGRAMMING'

Answer (score 1):

If you write $A$ as a vector $x$ (just stack the columns of $A$) both the numerator and the denominator are quadratic in $x$. Let's say the objective is $f(x) / g(x)$ with $g(x)>0$. Dinkelbach noticed that
$$\min_x \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \leq \alpha \Leftrightarrow \min_x \{f(x) - \alpha g(x) \} \leq 0. $$
This allows you to perform bisection search on $\alpha$. The trick is to find the smallest $\alpha$ such that the Hessian of $f(x) - \alpha g(x)$ is still positive semidefinite. After you find that $\alpha$, solve $\min_x \{f(x) - \alpha g(x) \}$ for the corresponding $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Request if you could give a reference to Dinkelbach paper. or any book.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju https://doi.org/10.1287/mnsc.13.7.492

Comment: In your answer, you may want to correct the sign from $\le$ to $\ge$ on both occasions, if I am not wrong.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju it is if and only if, so both the current answer and your suggestion are correct. My statement coincides with Lemma 5 in the paper (adjusted for minimization vs maximization).

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju Wouldn't my response below give you an analytic solution to your problem? To me, it looks like an eigenvalue problem in disguise

Comment: @BielRoig-Solvas I like your solution! They are both related to eigenvalues, but yours is more explicit.

Comment: @BielRoig-Solvas : I am not interested in this problem anymore, the reason being mentioned in your other answer which I recently accepted. I am interested in solving a coupled minimization and maximization problem, where instead of the above ratio, I try to minimize the numerator (slightly modified to incorporate a parameter) and simultaneously maximize the denominator. If you are interested in collaboration do email me : rajesh.dachiraju@gmail.com. Lastly, the functional being nonlinear, how would you justify stacking of real and imaginary parts, in your answer?

Comment: @BielRoig-Solvas : I readily accepted the answer by LinAlg, as it is understandable, sounds conceptual and easy to implement.

Comment: @LinAlg Thanks!!

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju: If your numerator looks like $x^T A x + \lambda x^T B x$, minimizing it with respect to lambda can be done by codiagonalizing both matrices, and you'll get a closed-form for the optimum with respect to lambda. Then you can just plug that in the denominator function. Feel free to ask a question with the actual functions you plan to use in numerator and denominator and I can sketch an answer.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju: Regarding the stacking of real/imaginary, all the forms in your problem are of the type $x^H x$, so the cross-terms between real and imaginary parts cancel. That's why you can just stack real and imaginary, so the inner product only has real-real and imag-imag interactions.

Comment: @BielRoigSolvas : I have solved the minimization with closed form expression. Problem is with maximization problem. I am not comfortable sharing the actual problem here.

Comment: @BielR : Thank you very much  indeed for your answers. They are helpful.

Comment: @BielRoig-Solvas : I have asked the question here : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3202829/2987

Answer (score 0):

Your optimization problem is:

$\text{min}_A \quad  \frac{m^2(DA-P)^H (DA-P) + (FA)^H(FA)}{A^HA}$

Rearranging terms, one gets:

$\text{min}_A \quad  \frac{A^H (m^2 D^HD + F^H F)A\; -\;2 m^2(P^H D A + P D^H A^H) \;+\; m^2 P^HP}{A^HA}$

While the problem is defined over complex vectors, one can always recast the problem over the reals of dimension 2m, by stacking the real and imaginary parts. The problem over the reals looks like:

$\text{min}_x \quad  f(x)\quad \quad \text{where } f(x) = \frac{x^T Q x}{x^T x} - \frac{b^T x}{x^T x} + \frac{c}{x^T x}$

We can see that the first term of $f(x)$ only depends on the direction of $x$, while the last term only depends on its norm. A natural re-parametrization is then $x = \alpha \hat{x}$, where $\alpha >= 0$ and $||\hat{x}||_2 = 1$ and $f(x)$ becomes:

$f(\hat{x},\alpha) = \hat{x}^T Q \hat{x} - \frac{b^T \hat{x}}{\alpha} + \frac{c}{\alpha^2}$

And the optimization problem then becomes:

$\text{min}_{\hat{x}  } \quad \text{min}_{\alpha\geq 0} \quad f(\hat{x},\alpha)$

Looking at the inner problem, we get that fixing $\hat{x}$, the problem becomes a minimization of a quadratic polynomial on $\frac{1}{\alpha}$. Taking the gradient w.r.t. $\alpha$ and equating to 0 leads to:

$\frac{b^T \hat{x}}{\alpha^2} -  \frac{2c}{\alpha^3} = 0 \quad \to \quad \alpha^* = \frac{2c}{b^T \hat{x}}$   or $\frac{1}{\alpha^*} = \frac{b^T \hat{x}}{2c}$

Plugging that in we get:
$f(\hat{x},\alpha^*) = \hat{x}^T Q \hat{x} - \frac{\hat{x} (b b^T) \hat{x}}{2c} + \frac{\hat{x} (b b^T) \hat{x}}{4c} = \hat{x}^T (Q - \frac{b b^T}{4c}) \hat{x}$

The outer problem becomes:
$\text{min}_{\hat{x}  } \quad \hat{x}^T (Q - \frac{b b^T}{4c}) \hat{x} \quad \text{s.t.} \quad ||\hat{x}||_2 = 1$

which is a simple eigenvalue problem, i.e. $\hat{x}^*$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the lowest eigenvalue of $(Q - \frac{b b^T}{4c})$. Given that $Q$ is built from the matrix D you mention and + rank 1 update, and that D is short and fat with orthogonal columns, you should be able to solve this eigenvalue problem more efficiently than standard methods for dense full-rank dense matrices.

Once you have $\hat{x}^*$, you can find the corresponding $\alpha^*$ using the formula above, and possibly flip the sign of $\alpha \hat{x}$ so that $b^T \hat{x}$ is positive (if you take a look at f(x), you can see that both the first and last terms are invariant to sign flip of $x$, so you can choose the sign that minimizes $-b^Tx$, which is the one for which $b^Tx\geq 0$).